# How many mails can be sent at a time?

Tags: smtp, massmail

Using google, yahoo and AOL smtp and PHPMailer how many mails can be sent at a time?

I tried to send 200 mails at a time from google after 40 or 45 it is giving the following error.

`SMTP Error: Data not accepted`.

and then i tried to reload and give only 1 address and the same error i have got.

what is the problem?

Comment: Chances are Google doesn't want you using them as a spam engine.

Comment: Have you considered Google is locking the account because it might consider it to appear like a spamming activity?  I wouldn't expect to be able to hit their servers so hard and not be noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give a general answer to it. Big email providers such as Google have their own strategy to discover spammers. For example, I had no problem to send a single mail to 85 in CC, but sending 85 to a single recipient causes problems with my provider.

If you intend to send mass emails like a newsletter, I highly recommend using a professional service for it. Otherwise it is very likely that your email server gets black-listed or your sender email address marked as spam. Therefore, I can't recommend using typical newsletter plugins or modules for your favorite CMS if you got more than a couple of users registered.

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/email-address-limit.html for more info

Comment: Thanx for the infos... but it is behaving in a strange way.. like from 1 google id more than 200 are goin at a time.. but from another 30-40 and from another even 1 is not going. funny...